# Non-parametric mean comparison with 2 unequal samples?

Tags: nonparametric, mean, sample-size, group-differences

As an spanish speaker, I apologize if my technical english isn't 100% accurate. This may be a simple question, but I haven't found a clear answer.

I have two independent groups: Group A: n=1520 / Group B: n=115

I want to compare their means on the scoring on a 15-item instrument in order to find significant differences. This scoring doesn't have a normal distribution. I understand that, with a normal distribution, a t-test for independent samples can be used and the unequal size of the samples isn't a problem (Please correct me if this assumption is incorrect). However, on this case I used Mann-Whitney U but I don't know if the difference of the sample sizes may be a problem, and if so, what kind of analysis can be done to get a reliable result.

Comment: Mann-Whitney is fine with unequal sample sizes. If you have further doubts perhaps you can edit your question to make them clear to us. (Nothing wrong with your English by the way.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was just reading that Mann-Whitney needs equal variance on the groups, which these don't have and I don't see an option for "don't assume equal variances" as in the t-test. Anything that can be done on this case?

Comment: Mann-Whitney has nothing to do with variances unless you want to treat it as a test of means in which case you need to assume equality of variances (amongst many other things).

Comment: That's the thing. I aim to compare the means on these two groups but Mann-Whitney assumes equal variance. Also the variables don't have normal distribution. On this case, is there an alternative analysis to compare means on two non-normal groups with unequal variances?

Comment: I think you need to investigate bootstrapping.